# MessageBroker.getMessageBroker(null) getting null pointer Exception

Tags: apache-flex

I am creating Dynamic Destinations

MessageBroker broker = MessageBroker.getMessageBroker(null);

```
        MessageService service = (MessageService) broker.getService("message-service");
        MessageDestination destination = (MessageDestination) service.createDestination("Group1");

        if (service.isStarted()) {
            destination.start();
        }
```

But I am getting Null Pointer Exception 
MessageBroker broker = MessageBroker.getMessageBroker(null);

Can Anyone Help Me

Answer (score 0):

You may be using Spring blazeds integration. Flex, by default uses `"__default__"` as the messageBroker id in which case your `MessageBroker.getMessageBroker(null)` holds true. However, Spring uses `"_messageBroker"` as the broker id. Therefore you might have to use

```
MessageBroker broker=MessageBroker.getMessageBroker("_messageBroker");
```

This URL says it even better....

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=72964

```
MessageBroker broker=MessageBroker.getMessageBroker(BeanIds.MESSAGE_BROKER);
```